# making double variables lower than 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, integer-division

in my ASP.NET project i did a survey page that uses Application to save the votes. I have a problem with the making of the percentages amount. I've tried many things. here is the problematic part of my code:

```
    double x = (count / sum) ;
    double f = (count1 / sum) ;
    double g = (count2 / sum) ;
    double h = (count3 / sum) ;
    if (sum > 0)
    {
        a = (int)x * 100;
        b = (int)f * 100;
        c = (int)g * 100;
        d = (int)h * 100;
    }
```

I used breakpoints and figured out that the problem was in the double variables: the (count/sum) equals 0 anyway.

Comment: you need to provide what the values are of count ...and sum

Comment: What are count and sum declared as?

Comment: Are count & sum integers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming `count` and `sum` are integer types.

The result of division of 2 integers is a truncated integer.

You need to cast one side of the division to a `double`, then the result will be `double`

So

```
((double)count)/sum
```

Comment: `+1` much cleaner example in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

What are the datatypes of `count`, `count[1-3]` and `sum`? If they are integral types, then integer division is performed. This

```
int    x = 100   ;
int    y = 300   ;
double z = x / y ;
```

yields the value `0.0` for `z`.

Try something like

```
double h = (double) ( count3 / sum ) ;
```

You might also want to move your test for `sum > 0` up: as coded, if `sum` is zero, you'll throw a `DivideByZeroException` before you get to your test, thus rendering your test moot.

Answer (score 1):

Your `count` and `sum` variables are probably integers. Cast one of them to double:

```
double x = count / (double)sum;
```

UPDATE:

Actually, if you want the percentage as an integer, you can skip the doubles altogether:

```
int a = 100 * count / sum;
```